# Database structure for products related to currencies and countries

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

In my application, there are many products/services offered by the company.

This is the structure:

> cities:

```
id
city_name
status
country
```

> products:

```
id
product_name
product_price
status
metadata
```

> countries:

```
id
country_name
currency
status
```

> currencies

```
id
currency
symbol
code
```

Currently,

1. one country has many cities
2. One country has one currency

Now, each product will have a different price in different cities.

How can I map product prices according to cities?
What would be universal structure, where it could suffice all the use cases?

Comment: and you want to stick with 1 currency per country forever ? Can you show the actual schema. The above is not fantastic if you already have a schema.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I have not defined the schema yet. This is just a planned out schema.

Answer (score 4):

Using Normalization helps.

```
cities table:
id
name
status
country_id (id in table countries)

countries table:
id
name
currency_id (id in table currencies)
status

products table:
id
name
**    product_price ** (should be removed from this table)
status
metadata 

currencies table:
id
currency
symbol
code

product_price_in_city table:
id
city_id     (id in table cities)
product_id  (id in table products)
product_price_in_city (just a number. currency and symbol should be retrieved from table currency. using JOINs.
**'city_id ,product_id' pair should be unique.**

cities:
ID | name       | country_id
1  | 'london'   | 98
2  | 'tokyo'    | 99

countries:
ID | name       | currency_id
98 | 'england'  | 121
99 | 'japan'    | 122

currencies:
ID | name       | symbol
121| 'Pound'    | 's1'
122| 'Yen'      | 's2'

products:
ID | name 
789| 'CD'
790| 'DVD'
791| 'Floppy !!!!'

product_price_in_city:
ID  | city_id  | product_id | product_price_in_city
9988| 1        | 789        | 667788
9989| 1        | 790        | 66779988
9990| 1        | 791        | 567
9991| 2        | 790        | 776655
9992| 2        | 791        | 998877
```

As you see,

```
CD  in London is 667788   Pound
DVD in London is 66779988 Pound
DVD in Tokyo  is 776655   Yen
```

Comment: So, the product_price_in_city will be a many-to-may relation between cities and products, right?